# Use Consul as xds management server for envoy proxy without consul connect

Tags: microservices, consul, envoyproxy, servicemesh

I am working on a project where I want to configure `envoy` using `consul` as the xds server. But I don't want to use `consul connect`. I only want to use consul for service discovery and the xds server.

> I have started the consul agent with `-dev` mode enabling the grpc endpoints and I have registered a service `hello-service` which i can see in the `consul ui`.

**My barebone envoy config**

```
# admin web panel
admin:
  access_log_path: ./admin_logs
  address:
    socket_address:
      address: 0.0.0.0
      port_value: 9902

dynamic_resources:
  cds_config:
    ads: {}

  ads_config:
    api_type: grpc
    transport_api_version: v3
    grpc_services:
      - google_grpc:
          target_uri: http://localhost:8502
          stat_prefix: grpc-xds-service
```

> I am trying to fetch some configuration like clusters/endpoints from consul for the registered `hello-service`, But when i start the envoy process I am getting this warning.

```
[2021-07-11 19:16:05.782][11825][warning][config] [bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/external/envoy/source/common/config/_virtual_includes/grpc_stream_lib/common/config/grpc_stream.h:93] StreamAggregatedResources gRPC config stream closed: 13,
```

What I could make of this error is that the connection to the management server is failing. But In the consul logs i can see the grpc port is up.

```
 Client Addr: [127.0.0.1] (HTTP: 8500, HTTPS: -1, gRPC: 8502, DNS: 8600)
```

Comment: I provided an answer with some alternative solutions that you may be able to use. As an aside, can I ask why you do not want to utilize Consul Connect?

Answer (score 1):

Consul's xDS server is not designed to be used outside of Connect, and as such has not been tested or validated to be able to provide CDS/EDS data outside of that context.

You may want to take a look at [consul-envoy-xds](https://github.com/gojek/consul-envoy-xds) or [envoy-control](https://envoy-control.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), both of which may provide the xDS functionality you're looking for without requiring you to deploy a full-blown service mesh.

Comment: Envoy control is exactly the kind of thing i was looking for. Thank you